# My first Ruby on Rails program error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have just installed Rails on window. I want to Show a message in view page by routing in `routes.rb` but message is not displayed. My rails version is `3.2.21 and ruby is 1.9.3p551`
I have made a controller from command prompt `rails generate controller welcome index`

welcome_controller

```
class WelcomeController < ApplicationController
  def index

  end
end
```

routes.rb is

```
ProjectApp::Application.routes.draw do
  get "welcome/index"
  root to: 'welcome/index'
end
```

i have added `root to: 'welcome/index'`

and view template `index.html.erb`

```
<h1>`Hello Rails!`</h1>
```

When i go through url[`http://localhost:3000/index`] it should show `Hello Rails` as output but it is showing welcome board only
I have followed steps from `http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html`

Answer (score 2):

Your root url is localhost:3000 instead localhost:3000/index

Comment: At localhost:3000 it dosenot show "Hello Rails " as output

Answer (score 1):

As Prashant4020 said, you need to set up a view in app/views/welcome/index.html.erb

Your routes.rb should be something like this.

```
root 'welcome#index'
get 'welcome#index'
```

Comment: i did same but i have not got message/output

Answer (score 0):

Add view to show customize message

views/welcome/index.html.erb

```
Welcome to Ruby on Rails
<%= here your code goes %>
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking to solve this problem . You need to install the latest version of node js (64 bit msi installer)and add it to the environment variable path(normally installer will do that for you in windows). it should fix it.